# Is it possible to pull different data sets from one column?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to write some code that looks down one column with strings based on some simple formulas. I can't seem to get it to recognize the different sets of data and paste them where I want them.

I have tried re writing the code a few different ways in which is looks at all the data and just offsets the destination row by 1. But it does not recognize that it is pull different data.

Below is the code that works. What it does is starts from the 1st column 2nd row (where my data starts). The data is a list like;

```
     A
1   Customer1
2   item1
3   item2
4   Item3 
5 
6   Customer2
7   Item1
```

The formulas that I have in those cells just concatenates some other cells.
 Using a loop it looks through column A and find the blank space. It then "breaks" whatever number it stops on, the numerical A1 notation of the cell, it then finds the values for those cells and transposes them In another sheet in the correct row.

The issue I am having with the code this code that has worked the best is it doesn't read any of the cells as blank 
(because of the formulas?) and it transposes all to the same row.

```
     function transpose(){
     var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var input =data.getSheetByName("EMAIL INPUT");
     var output = data.getSheetByName("EMAIL OUTPUT");
     var lr =input.getLastRow();


    for (var i=2;i<20;i++){
    var cell = input.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    if (cell == ""){
     break

     }

     }
    var set = input.getRange(2, 1, i-1).getValues();



      output.getRange(2,1,set[0].length,set.length) . 
     .setValues(Object.keys(set[0]).map ( function (columnNumber) {
     return set.map( function (row) {
     return row[columnNumber];
      });
      }));
      Logger.log(i);
      Logger.log(set);
       }
```

What I need the code to do is look through all the data and separate the sets of data by a condition.
Then Transpose that information on another sheet. Each set (or array) of data will go into a different row. With each component filling across the column (["customer1", "Item1","Item2"].

EDIT:
Is it Possible to pull different data sets from a single column and turn them into arrays? I believe being able to do that will work if I use "appendrow" to tranpose my different arrays to where I need them.

Comment: It looks that the code has some typos like `output.getRange(2,1,set[0].length,set.length) . ` then the next line `.setValues(Object.keys(set[0]).map ( function (columnNumber) {`. Did you have problems to pass your code here? By the other hand, please read [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén. I took parts of this script from another website when looking up transposing. Looking at the execution there doesn't seem to be any issues with this part of the code

Comment: @HannaLogan Detailed followup issues are normally raised as separate questions - partly to maintain a one question-one answer approach and partly because an "Edit" may not be seen by all those people best qualified to help. In any event, it's not clear from your "Edit" what you're trying to achieve (it doesn't have a context from your earlier question) and you've not provided an example of a successful outcome. Unless I have misunderstood your "edit", I think it might be best posed as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for the **length** of cell. Even if it is a formula, it will evaluate the result based on the value.

```
if (cell.length !=0){
  // the cell is NOT empty, so do this
}
else
{
  // the cell IS empty, so do this   instead
}
```

---

**EXTRA**
This code takes your objective and completes the transposition of data.

The code is not as efficient as it might/should because it includes `getRange` and `setValues` inside the loop.
Ideally the entire Output Range could/should be set in one command, but the (unanswered) challenge to this is knowing in advance the maximum number rows per contiguous range so that blank values can be set for rows that have less than the maximum number of rows.

This would be a worthwhile change to make.

---

```
function so5671809203() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputsheetname = "EMAIL_INPUT";
  var inputsheet = ss.getSheetByName(inputsheetname);

  var outputsheetname = "EMAIL_OUTPUT";
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName(outputsheetname);


  var inputLR =inputsheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+inputLR);
  var inputrange = inputsheet.getRange(1, 1,inputLR+1);
  Logger.log("the input range = "+inputrange.getA1Notation());
  var values = inputrange.getValues();

  var outputval=[];
  var outputrow=[];
  var counter = 0; // to count number of columns in array

  for (i=0;i<inputLR+1;i++){
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Row:"+i+", Value = "+values [i][0]+", Length = "+values [i][0].length);

    if (values [i][0].length !=0){
      // add this to the output sheet 
      outputrow.push(values [i][0]); 
      counter = counter+1;
      Logger.log("DEBUG: value = "+values [i][0]+" to be added to array. New Array Value = "+outputrow+", counter = "+counter);
    }
    else
    {
      // do nothing with the cell, but add the existing values to the output sheet
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Found a space - time to update output");

      // push the values onto an clean array
      outputval.push(outputrow);
      // reset the row array
      outputrow = []; 

      // get the last row of the output sheet
      var outputLR =outputsheet.getLastRow();
      Logger.log("DEBUG: output last row = "+outputLR);

      // defie the output range
      var outputrange = outputsheet.getRange((+outputLR+1),1,1,counter);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the output range = "+outputrange.getA1Notation());

      // update the values with array
      outputrange.setValues(outputval);

      // reset the row counter
      counter = 0;
      //reset the output value array
      outputval=[];
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Email Input and Output Sheets**
[image: Email Input Sheet] [image: Email Out Sheet]

Comment: @HannaLogan  If this answer was useful, then you might consider accepting it.